# Is horizontal line always parallel to the x-axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am having an argument about the answer of the following question with my friend:

Determine if the following sentence is always, sometimes or never true:
- A horizontal line is parallel to the x-axis.

I think it's 'always', but my friend thinks it's 'sometimes'.

My friend thinks that the answer is 'sometimes' because a horizontal line at x-axis is not parallel to x-axis, it is the x-axis.

We are unable to find any resources to prove it one way or other, and hoping this community would help.

Thanks.

Comment: There are differences of definition, so you are both right. The Euclidean definition (for the plane) is lines that do not meet. So under that definition your friend is right. for other purposes, it is convenient to say that a line is parallel to itself, making you right. If it was a test question, correctness depends on the "local" convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A horizontal line is always parallel to the $x$-axis.  Note that a line is considered to be parallel to itself.

Answer (score 0):

At your level of maths there is no other definition of line.

note that the form $y=mx+c$ where m is 0 is a line parallel to the x axis.

So yes.

To be parallel $\iff$ m is the same for both lines.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes; a horizontal line has the same slope as the x-axis. If the horizontal line is not y=0, then it is parallel to x-axis.